# Quick question about TypeScript and functions

Tags: angular, typescript, function, ide

I came from a java and python background and was picking up typescript for Angular. After 3 hours trying to solve a simple problem I figured out that

```
calculateYear(age) {
    this.birthYear = new Date().getFullYear()-age;
}
```

is not the same as

```
calculateYear(age) {
    this.birthYear = new Date().getFullYear-age;
}
```

My problem with this is that VSCode autocompleted to Date().getFullYear, and I kept assigning a function to a number and getting this:

`(error TS2322: Type '() => number' is not assignable to type 'number')`.

I wanted to know are there any circumstances that I would want to type *.getFullYear instead of *.getFullYear(). If not why did the IDE even have this option.

Comment: I don't know if there can be an authoritative answer to this.  Functions are first-class objects in JS/TS, so sometimes people want to refer to them instead of calling them.  And probably when designing autocomplete functionality in a language with first-class function objects, I would err on the side of just autocompleting them as property names and not calling them.  But that's just me.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJjAvDMBTA7jAIgQyqgCgEoBuAWAChRJYBzVKAFQAtUBNVHAJyXgDp6UAGIBXADZiO3PgCMAlmDgE4pGAHo1MVl1SVKcPhAaM5AW0IBGAKwB2AAxWAbHYBMAZjd2vpStQggxVD4xEFoCQRZ2Ti5iVQ0YFzsLAE49CgMjJjNLGys3AA4AFjs3Qo8vOx8qcH9A4NDw41YpGKI4zRcrTsogA) count as a time someone would want `d.getFullYear` without calling it directly?  It's using [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Creating_a_bound_function).

Answer (score 0):

in javascript, functions are first class citizens: you can assign them as values, pass them as arguments to functions, and even return them as a value.

```
calculateYear(age) {
   const getYear = new Date().getFullYear;
   this.birthYear = getYear()-age;
}
```

Comment: I really wouldn't try to call an unbound method like that; there's no `this` context and you're likely to get a runtime error.  If you're going to do this you might want something like `Date.prototype.getFullYear.bind(new Date())` instead.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at this.